# Can double copy address the weakness of gravity?

Tags: gravity, physical-constants, yang-mills, order-of-magnitude, double-copy

I hope I didn't miss a post that already answers this question. I am simply wondering if there is a natural framework in the [double copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copy_theory) approach to explain the weakness of gravity? I don't require that $G$ or the dimensionless gravitational coupling constant or the Planck scale magically drop out of nowhere. I simply wonder if there is a mechanism that suppresses the effective strength of the interaction in this model? I am happy to be told that this isn't even a conceptually good question.

Comment: Precisely what makes you believe that double copy can explain it?

Comment: Nothing. That's why I am asking. I was wondering what, in general, would be a good property of a microscopic theory of gravity that does not require it to become a TOE. The first thing that came to mind was whether it can explain the weakness of gravity in a straight forward manner. I believe to remember that compactified extra dimensions and branes are trying to attempt that feat, so I was wondering if double copy could, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [double copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copy_theory) is a perturbative structural comparison at the Feynman diagram level using [Bern-Carrasco-Johansson (BCJ)](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=BCJ+duality)/[color-kinematic](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=color+kinematic+duality) duality between correlation functions in gravity (GR) versus 2 copies of Yang-Mills (YM) theory. Here the coupling constants of GR and YM enter as formal parameters; their actual values are never used. The double copy is not relevant for the [weak gravity conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_gravity_conjecture) per se.

Comment: That was kind of my expectation, without the technical aspects, of course. I was not expecting that something in the dual copy approach would reduce the effective strength of the coupling. but wasn't sure. I appreciate the answer. I will try to read the Arkani-Hamed, Motl, Vafa paper.